# How to get value in Javascript while looping in jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp, jstl

I have the following JSP code:

```
<c:forEach items="${requestScope.XX}" var="x">
   <tr>
      <td><input type="radio" value="${x.xID}" name="x"></td>
      <td>&nbsp;${x.name}</td>
   </tr>    
</c:forEach>
```

Whenever the user clicks on radio button, I need to take both `x.xID` and 'x.name' and validate in Javascript.

How do I pass the the selected value to Javascript?

I tried with `onClick` function, but the value is not getting passed to Javascript.

```
function validate(y) {
   alert(y.value);
}
```

Comment: show us your java script code

Comment: You may use document.getElementsByName() method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm guessing that you are a bit confused about server-side (JSP) and client-side (JavaScript) code execution, but anyway:

```
<input type="radio" value="${x.xID}" name="x" onclick="validate('${x.xID}','${x.name}')" />
```

**Edit:** added single quotes for error-proofing.

**Edit 2:** as I'd guessed, you are a bit confused about where JavaScript is executed: it runs on the client, where the objects you had in JSP do not exist, and as such `y.value` is meaningless in `validate()`. Your function should be something like this:

```
function validate(id, name) { alert('id: ' + id + ', name: ' + name); }
```

Comment: Ya but onclick is not working. I have added simple javascipt for my code.

Comment: @freepublicview Try using `onclick="alert('${x.xID}, ${x.name}')"`, if that works it's a problem with your validate function, if not post the HTML output.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Ya i had some confusion, thanks for resolving